# Replace value within single quotes in a line that contains certain word using sed command

Tags: shell-script, sed, quoting

I have a line as below in a html file,

```
shahar.push(['remoteUrl', 'staging.zazzercode.com']);
```

Depending upon environment, I want to replace the `remoteUrl` value with `sed` command.

**eg,**

```
shahar.push(['remoteUrl', 'staging.zazzercode.com']);
shahar.push(['remoteUrl', 'production.zazzercode.com']);
```

I used

```
sed -i '/remoteUrl/c\shahar.push(['remoteUrl','staging.zazzercode.com']);' predict.html
```

It works but removing single quotes over `'remoteUrl'` and `'staging.zazzercode.com'` causing html error.

```
shahar.push([remoteUrl, staging.zazzercode.com]);
```

**So to be safe,** I want to change `sed` command just to change the value between two single quotes after `,` in a line with `remoteUrl`.

Or I want other `sed` options than What I knew to replace whole line but with single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `bash` is processing your command line before `sed` gets a hold of it.  In this case, the solutions is to change the outer quotes to double-quotes:

```
sed -i "/remoteUrl/c\shahar.push(['remoteUrl','staging.zazzercode.com']);" predict.html
```

The issue was that `bash` performs quote removal before passing the command to `sed`.  In bash's eyes, your original command was a series of single-quoted strings and `bash` removed all the quotes.  In the version above, `bash` sees a single double-quoted string.  While `bash` removes those double-quotes before passing the string to `sed`, it leaves the inner single-quotes alone.

Comment: true, I fixed that :)

Answer (score 1):

> **So, to be safe**, I want to change the `sed` command just to change the value
>   between two single quotes after a comma (`,`) in a line with `'remoteUrl'`.

```
sed "s/\('remoteUrl',.*'\).*\('\)/\1staging.zazzercode.com\2/"
```

`s` is search, substitute, and replace. 
`\(` and `\)` in the “old” string (specified first) identify substrings. 
`\1` and `\2` (and `\n`, up to `\9`) copy those substrings
into the replacement string.

Comment: Thx Scott, i'll check it later.